# Migrate SQL Server 2012 databases on premises to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, migration, azure-vm, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have SQL Server 2012 databases on premises and I would like to migrate these to Azure SQL

However the Application Vendor has not certified their Application on Azure SQL but the following versions of SQL Server: 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019.

Is SQL Server Managed Instance suitable or SQL Server in Azure VM?

Comment: check out this video (have to register):  https://www.idera.com/resource-center/webcasts/geeksync/sql-server-to-azure-migration/  slides here  https://www.slideshare.net/IderaSoftware/geek-sync-planning-a-sql-server-to-azure-migration-in-2021-brent-ozar

Answer (score 1):

> Is SQL Server managed instance suitable

From [What is Azure SQL Managed Instance?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/sql-managed-instance-paas-overview?view=azuresql):

> SQL Managed Instance has **near 100% compatibility** with the latest SQL Server (Enterprise Edition) database engine, providing a native virtual network (VNet) implementation that addresses common security concerns, and a business model favorable for existing SQL Server customers. SQL Managed Instance allows existing SQL Server customers to lift and shift their on-premises applications to the cloud with minimal application and database changes.

Despite Microsoft claiming such closeness between Azure SQL Managed Instance and SQL Server, there are certainly a number of individual differences between the two. Most of the differences are what's accessible at the server level which then results in limitations on server level features such as Linked Servers, Replication, SQL Agent / Jobs, Security, file share access, etc. You can read on the specific differences in [T-SQL differences between SQL Server & Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server?view=azuresql).

The only way to be safe is to check with your vendor and get their approval. Otherwise, I think trying to use an Azure SQL Managed Instance will potentially result in you running into some kind of issue, since there are a multitude of granular differences.

> or SQL Server in Azure VM?

An Azure VM hosting a regular SQL Server instance is going to be no different than any other VM elsewhere (on-prem or not) hosting a SQL Server instance. When configured properly, there should *almost* no difference and the risk for issues should be extremely minimal. Again, confirm with your Vendor, but I'm sure they'd agree they'd support this scenario.